# NodeJS socket client - callback para cada requisição

Tags: node.js, socket

Tenho o seguinte código

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});
```

Preciso enviar várias mensagens de uma só vez para o server e preciso processar cada uma das respostas, acontece que o node é assíncrono, ou seja, não tenho uma ordem de resposta. os comandos abaixo dispara o evento `client.on('data'function(data) {...` porém eu não consigo saber exatamente a resposta de cada requisição, o ideal seria executar de forma síncrona mas não conseguir.

```
   client.write('Algumacoisa1');
   client.write('Algumacoisa2');
   client.write('Algumacoisa3');
```

Pelo manual [net socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback) `socket.write(data[, encoding][, callback])` ví que posso usar assim :

```
  client.write('algumacoisa', 'utf8', function(data){
     console.log(data); //data sempre é undefined

   })
```

resumindo, eu quero que para cada `client.write` eu receba a sua resposta e somente depois eu enviar mais `client.write`para o servidor.

Eu sei que esse problema todo é pelo fato do node ser assíncrono, como resolver?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) para isso:

```
async.series([function(done){
    client.write('uma mensagem', 'utf8', function(data){
      console.log('primeira mensagem enviada');;
      done();
    });
  },function(done){
    client.write('outra mensagem', 'utf8', function(data){
      console.log('segunda mensagem enviada');
      done();
    });
  },function(done){
    client.write('terceira mensagem', 'utf8', function(data){
      console.log('terceira mensagem enviada');
      done();
    });
  },function(done){
    console.log('todas mensagens enviadas');
    done();
}]);
```

Este código só vai enviar a próxima mensagem quando a anterior receber uma resposta.

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, eu envio um array de funções a serem executadas, blz, mas o problema é que essa funções serão executadas as medidas que são enviadas requests, então esse array é dinâmico. Se o cara envia uma request, ai executo com o com o async, blz, mas depois é enviada outra request, vou executar novamente o async? estou achando que a solução vai ser usar uma pilha de execuções das requests.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com o link para a documentação do [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback). Cada item da array é uma função, que são executadas em sequência, uma após o término da outra. Executando o código acima você terá as mensagens de saída sempre na mesma sequência, como havia perguntado.